# How can I match a standalone IP to a CIDR?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm using Maxmind's geolocation tables (specifically down to city/country level), one of these tables has this structure:

[image]

I store the IPs of the users of my service in another table; I have created `latitude` and `longitude` columns and want to store the applicable latitude and longitude of these IPs within the users table (in the corresponding row for the IP).

As can be seen, IPs in the MaxMind table are stored in CIDR format, meaning that it's not possible to *directly* check whether an IP fits within the IP range given by the CIDR.

Is it possible to match a regular IP to CIDR format using only a MySQL statement?

I tried this but however have found the following:

- It *is* possible, but I need the subnet mask (which I don't have)
- I *can* get the subnet mask from the raw IP, however it requires the CIDR...

As matching the IPs in the `users` table to CIDR notation in the MaxMind table will take a while, I'm using a standard C# CLI program to handle the batch, and I acknowledge that I can do this:

1. Retrieve the the *entire* MaxMind table into a data reader
2. Go though each row and convert the CIDR to an IP range
3. At the same time, open a data reader to the `users` table and match the given IP into the IP range
4. `UPDATE` the corresponding record in `users` with the latitude and longitude that matches the CIDR from earlier

As you can see, my method seems (to me) quite inefficient and may take much, much more time than it should require.

---

Can I match a regular IP to a CIDR simply using a MySQL statement? If not, can I calculate the IP range *without* the subnet mask and then match the IP?

The columns that are relevant in the `users` table are as follows:

[image]

Comment: "Can I match a regular IP to a CIDR simply using a MySQL statement?" No. "can I calculate the IP range without the subnet mask and then match the IP?" No. How could you possibly know the range without the subnet mask?

Comment: One approach would be to add a column.  The CIDR is just a bit mask of the network portion of the address after all, so for each range, you have a column with just the network portion (as an integer.)  Then you can take the IP you're looking for, start at the end and start making the network portion shorter and shorter until you either get a match or run out of bits.  That would be < 23 queries.  Brute force and ugly.  Can you do it with just MySQL?  I'd be surprised.

Comment: @itsme86 I'm trying to find a way to store the latitude and longitude for the IPs within the `users` table with what I have at my disposal, without resorting to a paid geolocation service.

Comment: @Duston If it's possible, that'll be grand. If not, I don't mind too much about doing most of the work for this in the C# batch program.

Comment: You can make use of the inet_aton() function.   inet_aton(CIDR) = (inet_aton('154.154.133.1') & 0xFFF0) for example to test if the user's address is within the same /24 as the CIDR.  Come to think of it, you really don't care about the incoming address' net, just whether it matches the first x bits of the CIDR (which you have in your table.)

Comment: Nevermind that last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I wrote this class some time ago for checking if an IP address falls within a range. You just have to split the network and the mask in the CIDR string, parse them and pass them into the constructor. Then you can just use `ContainsIP()` to see if that IP address falls within that network. It could probably use another constructor that accepts a CIDR string to handle the splitting/parsing for you.

```
public class IPNetwork
{
    private readonly IPAddress _networkMask;
    private readonly int _networkMaskLength;
    private readonly uint _networkMaskValue;

    public IPNetwork(IPAddress networkMask, int networkMaskLength)
    {
        if (networkMask.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only IPv4 networks are supported.");

        _networkMask = networkMask;
        _networkMaskLength = networkMaskLength;
        _networkMaskValue = GetMaskedAddress(networkMask);
    }

    public bool ContainsIP(IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
        return GetMaskedAddress(ipAddress) == _networkMaskValue;
    }

    private uint GetMaskedAddress(IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
        byte[] bytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
        int addressLength = bytes.Length * 8;
        uint addressValue = BytesToValue(bytes);

        uint maskedAddress = 0;
        for (int i = addressLength - _networkMaskLength; i < addressLength; ++i)
            maskedAddress |= addressValue & (1U << i);

        return maskedAddress;
    }

    private uint BytesToValue(byte[] bytes)
    {
        uint value = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
            value |= (uint)(bytes[bytes.Length - i - 1] << (i * 8));

        return value;
    }
}
```